# Слетел перевод при закрытии вопроса и в очереди на закрытие

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, выкатили обновление. Добавляю переводы в Традусёр. В ближайшие дни появится на сайте.

**UPD:** часть переводов добавлял по памяти и мог ошибиться. Обновление уже появилось на сайте. Если заметите какой-то недочёт, пишите в комментариях или отдельным вопросом с меткой [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) ^_^

Comment: То есть причины "не по теме" теперь в явном виде вообще нет? Ну классные у них обновления, нечего сказать...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight такое видение ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . В обсуждениях ссылались на [это](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210314/260198) обсуждение.

Comment: Хм, действительно, идея в целом правильная. Просто на ENSO есть причины типа "It's about general computing hardware and software." для закрытия не по теме, а у нас их нету. Поэтому сейчас людям будет непонятно, как их закрывать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight можно добавить в этот список новую причину.